# How to get an access token from Facebook to use in my Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, oauth

I'm currently working on an android application that has an activity which is showing the timeline photos of a public Facebook page.

I'm using the manual token from the graph api explorer, however, now that my testing is done id like to replace it with one that does not expire after 2 hours OR find some way to refresh the old one every time it expires (I was thinking doing it whenever the old one gets 400'd).

The current URL I'm using to get the timeline photo album JSON is this:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/xxxxxxxxxxx/photos?access_token= + MY_MANUAL_GRAPH_API_TOKEN

I need this token to get the JSON from the public timeline album (for the image urls), nothing else. I do not want anyone to log in or anything like that.

Any ideas? I've looked at the official Facebook Access Tokens documentation and other answers here but I feel like I'm not finding anything that's relevant to what I'm looking for.

Comment: When the user logs in you get an access token

Comment: Are you using the Facebook SDK? Cause you should use the Facebook SDK.

Comment: @MingLi I thought I'd get away without using the SDK for such a simple thing. Guess I'll have to look into using the SDK.

Comment: See section 7.2 of the Facebook Platform Policy doc: https://developers.facebook.com/policy#login